# Efficient way to CASE and ALIAS using multiple column values

Tags: sql-server, case, sql-server-2019

I have some simple key-value pair data tracking the user and the datetime for when specific edits for an "encounter" were made, like a dr visit where they take your BP (who and when) and your pulse (who and when) and your temperature (who and when).

Here is a sample of the data:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable ( [encounterId] int, [rn] bigint, [eventDt] datetime2(3), [revisedBy] nvarchar(101), [TypeId] int )
INSERT INTO #temptable ([encounterId], [rn], [eventDt], [revisedBy], [TypeId])
VALUES
( 1, 1, N'2021-11-12T08:43:04', N'Samantha B', 4 ), 
( 2, 1, N'2021-11-11T14:08:24', N'Testuser02 L', 1 ), 
( 2, 1, N'2021-11-11T14:08:28', N'Testuser02 L', 2 ), 
( 3, 1, N'2021-11-22T12:00:47', N'Johnny S', 1 ), 
( 3, 2, N'2022-04-08T10:03:49', N'Johnny S', 1 ), 
( 6, 1, N'2021-11-22T11:57:59', N'Johnny S', 1 ), 
( 7, 1, N'2021-11-24T08:46:49', N'Johnny V', 1 ), 
( 13, 1, N'2022-03-28T13:33:24', N'Johnny S', 4 ), 
( 14, 1, N'2022-03-28T13:34:42', N'Johnny S', 4 )

SELECT * from #temptable
DROP TABLE #temptable
```

**Notes**
The TypeId values are known values (e.g. 1="Procedure Started", 2="Procedure Ended", etc.), there are 5 TypeIds, and the TypeId can happen multiple times per encounterId, so I have added a row_number (rn) per encounterId, TypeId order by eventDt to mark these instances.

**The problem I'm trying to solve**

I need to pivot these values out for encounterId but ***I can't use PIVOT or Stored Procedures*** in my application's technology (custom reporting tool). I'm going to have to CASE through the results and pivot the values that way so that each encounterId has a single row showing each pair of TypeId (when) and TypeIdRevisedBy (who). I'm concerned about efficiency with a CASE statement repeating 15 times (five TypeId options x three potential uses each per encounterId).

Here is a working model of my CASE statements but it seems wonky to hard-code the column aliases and to have each two-layer CASE statement run in full each time:

```
SELECT encounterId
, CASE WHEN TypeId=1 AND rn=1 THEN eventDt END AS [1Procedure Started]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=1 AND rn=1 THEN revisedBy END AS [1Procedure Started Revised By]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=1 AND rn=2 THEN eventDt END AS [2Procedure Started]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=1 AND rn=2 THEN revisedBy END AS [2Procedure Started Revised By]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=1 AND rn=3 THEN eventDt END AS [3Procedure Started]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=1 AND rn=3 THEN revisedBy END AS [3Procedure Started Revised By]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=2 AND rn=1 THEN eventDt END AS [1Procedure Ended]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=2 AND rn=1 THEN revisedBy END AS [1Procedure Ended Revised By]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=2 AND rn=2 THEN eventDt END AS [2Procedure Ended]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=2 AND rn=2 THEN revisedBy END AS [2Procedure Ended Revised By]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=2 AND rn=3 THEN eventDt END AS [3Procedure Ended]
, CASE WHEN TypeId=2 AND rn=3 THEN revisedBy END AS [3Procedure Ended Revised By]
--repeat loop through TypeId=5
    FROM #temptable
```

**The Question(s)**

1. Is there a more efficient way for me to CASE through both checks (TypeId and rn)?
2. Is there a more efficient way to alias the columns in the CASE using the rn column's value (as seen in my hard-coded aliases, but automagically)?

Comment: Pivoting is normally something for your application layer, *not* the SQL layer. Especially wehen you want to pivot on the row number, which means that you don't have an upper limit. So yes, there is a more effeciant way; use an actual reporting tool to do this.

Comment: There isn't anything *inefficient* about what you are doing (`PIVOT` compiles down to the same thing) it's just verbose

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface. I used the CASE as I had in my sample and it works for this narrow use case. I appreciate the feedback!